# Producer-Consumer w/ pthreads + semaphores in C (buffer slots accessed simultaneously)

Tags: c, pthreads, buffer, semaphore, producer-consumer

I have written a multi-threaded producer-consumer program in C. My initial program was not Minimal/Complete/Verifiable, so I have rewritten it from scratch and the bug is still happening. I'm finding that multiple producer threads are trying to produce the same data (from a sequence of data), and I'm not sure how to stop this.

Some things I have tried:
- I created a bool array the same size as the buffer to make sure the threads were only putting data in an empty slot, and taking from one with data in it, this solved one issue
- I tried moving the input/output slot incrementation to the beginning of the producer/consumer while loops (respectively) but it causes a deadlock

Another unrelated issue (I may well be able to solve myself tomorrow, but for now it is as is) is that many of the values in the sequence are skipped over, although I want them all to be produced.

PLEASE NOTE: I have been learning C for one month and this is also my first post on here. I have learnt so much from this site over the last few years, and I'm aware that sometimes the responses on here can be pretty harsh, so please be kind to someone who earnestly wants to learn and improve. Thanks! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

char * Buffer;
int nBufferSlots = 10;
int nThreads = 2;
pthread_t Producers, Consumers;
sem_t Empty, Full, Mutex;
int inputSlot;
int outputSlot;
char value = 0;
char SlotOccupationBoolArray[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void * producer(void *args)
{
    while(1)
    {
        sleep( rand() % 3);

        value++;

        sem_wait(&Empty);
        sem_wait(&Mutex);

        if (SlotOccupationBoolArray[inputSlot] == 0)
        {
            Buffer[inputSlot] = value;
            SlotOccupationBoolArray[inputSlot] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            value--;
        }

        inputSlot = (inputSlot + 1) % nBufferSlots;

        sem_post(&Mutex);
        sem_post(&Full);

        printf("\n[ ");
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", Buffer[i]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
}
void * consumer(void *args)
{
    while(1)
    {
        sleep( rand() % 5);

        sem_wait(&Full);
        sem_wait(&Mutex);

        if (SlotOccupationBoolArray[outputSlot] == 1)
        {
            char ValueConsumed = Buffer[outputSlot];
            printf("\nConsumed value: %d\n", ValueConsumed);
            Buffer[outputSlot] = 0;
            SlotOccupationBoolArray[outputSlot] = 0;
        }

        outputSlot = (outputSlot + 1) % nBufferSlots;

        sem_post(&Mutex);
        sem_post(&Empty);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    sem_open("/Mutex", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
    sem_open("/Full", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 0);

    Buffer = (char*) malloc(nBufferSlots*sizeof(char));

    sem_open("/Empty", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, nBufferSlots);

    Producers = (pthread_t) malloc(nThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));
    Consumers = (pthread_t) malloc(nThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));

    // set charBuffer elements to 0
    for (char i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&Producers, NULL, producer, NULL);
        pthread_create(&Consumers, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<nThreads;i++){
        int err = pthread_create(&Producers,NULL,producer,NULL);
        if(err != 0){
            printf("Error creating producer %d\n",i+1);
        }else{
            printf("Successfully created producer %d\n",i+1);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<nThreads;i++){
        int err = pthread_create(&Consumers,NULL,consumer,NULL);
        if(err != 0){
            printf("Error creating consumer %d\n",i+1);
        }else{
            printf("Successfully created consumer %d\n",i+1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

All I have printing to output is the Buffer array with current values (each time a producer thread is run) and each value that has been consumed.

What I would like to see in the output is something like this:

- [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
- [ 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
- [ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
- Consumed value: 1
- [ 0 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
- [ 0 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 ]
- Consumed value: 3
- [ 0 2 0 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 ]
- Consumed value: 4
- [ 0 2 0 0 5 6 0 0 0 0 ]
- [ 0 2 0 0 5 6 7 0 0 0 ]

But, instead I am seeing something like this (the duplicate 2/4 are the issue):

- [ 2 2 4 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 ]
- [ 2 2 4 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 ]
- [ 2 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 0 0 ]
- Consumed value: 2
- Consumed value: 2
- [ 0 0 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 ]
- Consumed value: 4

(Apologies for the formatting)

Comment: Hello there, welcome to SO! This is a good question. Could you provide the definition of `CONSUMER` and `PRODUCER`? My guess is that they are macros? And I believe `Signal`, `Empty` and `Full` are three variables of type `sem_t`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you presented a [mcve].  At minimum, declarations of all objects, functions, and macros are relevant. Also, your code should actually be *valid*.  For example, C does not have whole-array assignment, so given `array` declared as a `char[25]`, the assignment `array = arrayOfValues[callCount]` is invalid and should be rejected by your compiler.

Comment: Hey joH1, consumer and producer are functions that get called from the main function. Yes those 3 are semaphores.

Comment: Hey John, I wasn't sure of how much code I should show since I don't know where the problem is. What you mentioned about the array, I cut out some code so as to try and show only the relevant parts. I will rewrite the code up here. Thanks for your advice, it is much appreciated.

Comment: "I don't know what the problem is" is an *excellent* reason to spend the effort to produce a *bona fide* MCVE. Follow the hyperlink in my previous comment for more details about what we're looking for and ways you can create it.  Producing a MCVE is a genuine, powerful debugging technique in its own right, and if the exercise does not help you identify the bug yourself then it makes it much more likely that we can do so.

Comment: I will indeed do just that, thank you again. I will edit further when I've got myself an MCVE :)

Comment: Is the code now presented actually representative of your actual program?  The semaphore names and usage within seem inconsistent, with *four* semaphores where before there were three, and posts to `Empty` but no one waiting on it.  Please, *cut & paste* working code that exhibits the problem, or excerpts of such code at worst.  Doing anything else carries a high risk of wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Sarah What are initial values of semaphores you are using? I think there are few deadlock conditions if the initial values are 1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for your MCVE link, it was very helpful. I have rewritten my program and am still finding the error of threads accessing data when they shouldn't. I have cut and pasted my working code here and tried to name things intuitively.

Comment: @MayurK, my initial values are 0 for Full, Empty is the value of the number of buffer slots I have, and for the mutex one (it was named Signal) it is initialised at 0. After having rewritten my code to it's simplest form and trying to debug it, I've been experiencing some deadlock scenarios. From all other producer/consumer programs I have looked at that use semaphores, these seem to be the default values used. Are they incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Values are getting skipped and/or repeated because in `producer()` function, `value++` is done outside the mutex/semaphores and reading of the value as well as `value--` are done inside.

One thing you should remember is that threads can get scheduled in any random way by OS. So you should protect the resources which are shared between multiple threads using mutex/semaphore or any other mechanisms.

In your program, the following sequence is possibly happening.

1. Initally value=0. Producer-1 thread comes and does `value++`. Now value=1. It gets both `Empty` and `Mutex`.
2. Before Producer-1 writes the value to buffer slot, Producer-2 get scheduled and it does `value++`. Now value=2. Producer-2 will get `Empty` but it has to wait for `Mutex` as it is locked by Producer-1.
3. Now Producer-1 get scheduled again. Since `value=2`, at this point of time, it writes the same to buffer slot. After writing, it unlocks both `Empty` and `Mutex`.
4. After this, Producer-2 get scheduled. It gets `Mutex` as Producer-1 has unlocked it. Still `value=2` so it will write the same to buffer slot.
5. Please note, If another Producer thread gets scheduled before Producer-2 writing, the `value` may still get altered. Since value is updated outside `Mutex`, there is no limit on how many times it can get altered/ number is skipped.

So, what is the solution for this problem?

Move the code updating value (or any shared resource to be generic) inside mutex in `producer()`. In your code, you don't have to do `value++` first and if slot is not available do `value--`. Best solution is to update the value while writing to buffer slot as below.

```
    //value++; //Don't update it here. Move it to critical section of the code, inside mutex.

    sem_wait(&Empty);
    sem_wait(&Mutex);

    if (SlotOccupationBoolArray[inputSlot] == 0)
    {
        Buffer[inputSlot] = ++value; //Update and assign value, Read about pre-increment
        SlotOccupationBoolArray[inputSlot] = 1;
    }
    //else //This section is not required.
    //{
    //    value--;
    //}
```

Apart from this, there is one more issue. `sem_post` for `Full` should happen when a Producer writes to a slot in the buffer. Similarly, `sem_post` for `Empty` should happen when a Consumer reads from a slot in the buffer.

But you are doing `sem_post` in each loop. It will cause some issues. So take care of this also. Do `sem_post` for `Full`/`Empty` only when read/write happens.

PS: Mutex and semaphores are different concepts. Using them appropriately based on the use-case is essential for good, effective and more readable programming.